# Using JUserHelper class outside of Joomla - in custom script

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I am moving a joomla user database to a new custom CMS but I want to include the joomla helper class for salt. How can I `include` functions from the helper.php in my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the question.

I am just generating my own randoms and following Joomla's login protocol

Register:

```
$salt = uniqid('', true);
$crypt = md5($password.$salt);
$password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

Sign in

```
if( $row !== false )
{
    $parts = explode( ':', $row['password']);

    // Check if password is md5-ed with or without salt
    if (count($parts) < 2) 
        $new_password = md5($_GET["password"]);
    else 
    {
        // get some salt
        $salt = $parts[1];

        // convert the raw password to Joomla md5(password+salt):salt model
        $new_password = md5($_GET["password"] . $salt) . ":" . $salt;
    }

    // authenticate
    if ( $new_password != $row['password'] )
        echo "NO";  // your params
    else
        echo "YES," . $row['name'] . "," . $row['email'];  // your params

    // clean up
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
```